# can we still use schema in Kafka without schema registry?

Tags: apache-kafka

Per my understanding typically we will use schema in kafka topic to handle message serialization/deserialization, and typically we register our schema in schema registry, here are some questions on this:

1. if my team haven't built schema registry, can we still use schema in kafka topic and message?
2. do we have to build schema registry in confluent schema registry or we can build somewhere in our company's gitlab.com environment?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but you don't need a registry to use a serializer interface with a strict schema model

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own schema using confluent library

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Your schema written in avro

```
{
     "type": "record",
     "namespace": "com.github.felipegutierrez.kafka.registry.avro.pojo",
     "name": "Customer",
     "version": "1",
     "fields": [
       { "name": "first_name", "type": "string", "doc": "First Name of Customer" },
       { "name": "last_name", "type": "string", "doc": "Last Name of Customer" },
       { "name": "age", "type": "int", "doc": "Age at the time of registration" },
       { "name": "height", "type": "float", "doc": "Height at the time of registration in cm" },
       { "name": "weight", "type": "float", "doc": "Weight at the time of registration in kg" },
       { "name": "automated_email", "type": "boolean", "default": true, "doc": "Field indicating if the user is enrolled in marketing emails" }
     ]
}
```

And then you create your kafka producer and consumer. Here is a full running example: https://github.com/felipegutierrez/explore-kafka/tree/master/kafka-schema-registry-avro-V1

Comment: The serializer still requires a running schema registry server